# Azure python3 SDK - recovery_service_client - Error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_token'

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I need a python script, to list all Recovery service vaults in a particular resource group.

Here is my code:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AccessToken
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.recoveryservices import RecoveryServicesClient


# Initialize Service Principal credentials
tenant_id = "88888888-jhgf-7865-CCCC-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
client_id = "99999999-lkjk-9877-ljhg-YYYYYYYYYYYY"
client_secret = "gfhgfhgvbkjgftyrdthgjklkjlljfhfhgfhg"
subscription_id = "yyyyyyyy-xxxx-kkkk-njjjj-ddddddddddd"


# Define the resource URI for which you want to obtain a token
resource_uri = "https://management.azure.com/"

# Create a ClientSecretCredential object with the client credentials
creds = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

# Get an access token that is valid for the next 10 minutes
token = creds.get_token(resource_uri + "/.default" )
expires_on = token.expires_on
access_token = AccessToken(token.token, expires_on)

print(access_token.token)

recovery_service_client = RecoveryServicesClient(credential=access_token.token, subscription_id=subscription_id, base_url=resource_uri)
# List all Recovery Services vaults in the resource group
resource_group_name = "rg_myexample"
vaults = recovery_service_client.vaults.list_by_resource_group(resource_group_name)

# Iterate over the vaults and print their names
for item in vaults:
    print(type(item))
    print(item)
```

I could print access_token.token and validate the token using https://jwt.ms/.

But when I try to  Iterate over vaults. I get below mentioned error.

```
  File "D:\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\policies\_authentication.py", line 93, in on_request
    self._token = self._credential.get_token(*self._scopes)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_token'
```

Please help me , I did not find much documentation on it Or working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because [`RecoveryServicesClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-recoveryservices/azure.mgmt.recoveryservices.recoveryservicesclient?view=azure-python) constructor expects a credential parameter of type [`TokenCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-core/azure.core.credentials.tokencredential?view=azure-python) and not string (which is what you are passing).

Please change the following line of code:

```
recovery_service_client = RecoveryServicesClient(credential=access_token.token, subscription_id=subscription_id, base_url=resource_uri)
```

to

```
recovery_service_client = RecoveryServicesClient(credential=creds, subscription_id=subscription_id, base_url=resource_uri)
```

And that should fix the error you are getting.

Comment: I also need to update my package azure_mgmt_recoveryservices-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl along with your sugesstion